# Code signing fail in Visual studio post-build event

Tags: visual-studio, code-signing

I'm having an issue signing throught Visual Studio post-build event.

When I sign the file through power shell it works fine, but when I try to sign it in a post-build event in Visual Studio I get the message: The specified PFX password is not correct.

I've checked and the password is correct.

Here my Post-build event:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22000.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /f "pfxFilePath.pfx" /as /fd sha256 /p password  "$(TargetPath)"

Comment: Looks like an unmatched `"` before `password` - is that real or did it appear when posting the question?

Comment: It appear when posting. But I've already tried "password"  and only password without  "" same result.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found out the issue. My pfx password contained special characters like %, when running the command line through power shel it was fine but when I've tried to run it through Visual Studio post build event, it failed. I just removed the % from the password and it worked.